# Save and email or save button on generate document page on click getting below error

Tags: community, cpq

We have using cpq functionality for the partner user but on generated document page on click save and email button we are facing below error.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/8tSd6.png

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE). While screenshots are usually very helpful, and links in general are not discouraged, it is usually better to embed your screenshot into your question rather than link to a screenshot. This is for a couple of reasons: 1) It will catch someone's attention when they click into your question, whereas they might skip it if they need to click a link; 2) "links tend to change or go dead over time". You can [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/355460/edit) your question and just copy/paste the image into the text.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Also, I just learned this from reading a comment that @sfdcfox recently added to a question: "Please don't post error messages as screenshots, as it is not as accessible to users that use screen readers or other assistive technology." So you need to at least put the _exact_ error message in text as part of your question.